# intArray to doubleArray, Out Of Memory Exception C#

Tags: c#, macos, exception, memory, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to convert a 10,000 by 10,000 int array to double array with the following method (I found in this website)

```
public double[,] intarraytodoublearray( int[,] val){ 

        int rows= val.GetLength(0);
        int cols = val.GetLength(1);
        var ret = new double[rows,cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
            {
                ret[i,j] = (double)val[i,j];
            }
        }
        return ret;
}
```

and the way I call is

```
 int bound0 = myIntArray.GetUpperBound(0);
 int bound1 = myIntArray.GetUpperBound(1);
 double[,] myDoubleArray = new double[bound0,bound1];  
 myDoubleArray = intarraytodoublearray(myIntArray)  ;
```

it gives me this error,

```
Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory
at (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_2 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

The machine has 32GB RAM, OS is MAC OS 10.6.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you're trying to create an array of 100 million doubles (each of which will take 800MB) - *twice*:

```
// This line will allocate an array...
double[,] myDoubleArray = new double[bound0,bound1];  
// The method allocates *another* array...
myDoubleArray = intarraytodoublearray(myIntArray);
```

Why bother initializing `myDoubleArray` to an empty array and then reassigning the value? Just use:

```
double[,] myDoubleArray = intarraytodoublearray(myIntArray);
```

That will halve the amount of memory used for one thing. Now whether or not it'll work at that point, I'm not sure... it depends on how Mono deals with large objects and memory. If you're using a lot of memory, you definitely want to make sure you're using a 64-bit VM. For example:

```
gmcs -platform:x64 ...
```

(The important assembly to compile with this option is the main application which will start up the VM. It's not clear what kind of application you're writing.)

As an aside, `intarraytodoublearray` is a horrible name - it uses the alias `int` instead of the framework `Int32` name, and it ignores the capitalization conventions. `Int32ArrayToDoubleArray` would be better.

Comment: One more thing: The way he creates the first, unneeded double array is incorrect. Each dimension is one element too small.

Comment: hey Jon thanks, I think its a mono related problem, now I am updating,  I thought 2*800 mb would not be problem for a 32gb machine, but never thought about x64 VM.                               and for the naming part I agree to you, as I told before, I did not write that method. I took it from here, so I didnt change to remember that I took it somewhere.